# AngularJs version of Blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, angularjs, blueimp

I need multiple bluimp jquery file upload widgets in the same page. I am using Angular version. Can someone help me how i can add multiple wizards in the same page.

for the single file upload wizard i am doing like this:

```
<div  data-file-upload="options">           

                             <input type="file"
                                name="files[]" id="show_pclp"
                                >
                        </span>

                    <div  data-ng-repeat="file in queue"
                        data-ng-switch="file.type">
                        <div data-ng-switch-when="image/png">&nbsp;{{file.name}}</div>
                        <div data-ng-switch-when="image/jpeg">&nbsp;{{file.name}}</div>
                        <div data-ng-switch-when="image/gif">&nbsp;{{file.name}}</div>
                        <div data-ng-switch-default>
                            <span ng-init="unsuportedFile();"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

i want another div with for the second upload in the same form

if i give for second div like this data-file-upload="option1" it is not working. second file upload also going to first file upload.

Basically i need 2 different file upload options in the same conroller.

Comment: Angular creates a new scope for each directive. What's not working?

Comment: Thanks Austin for the reply! I edited my question with the information.

Comment: It looks to me like the only invalid thing is you have an ID specified inside the upload form. IDs must be unique.

Comment: i changed the id to be unique. but no luck. can i give anything to the data-file-upload value instead of options? and define that in js.